# Main will not set to 100% height - Codepen included

Tags: html, css

**Question Background:**

I am looking into a sliding menu panel and have the following codepen to display this:

http://codepen.io/daveharris/pen/pEvEad

**The Issue:**

The `<main>` component has a `slide-panel` style applied to it which is the following:

```
#main {
    background: red;
    height: 100vmin!important;
}
```

In the mobile view the `<main>` component is not setting to a height of 100%, this is displayed with the use of a red background colour, as shown:

[image]

This height issue means that when the panel is closed, the underlying menu can be seen as shown:

[image]

**I cannot work out why the styling of 100% is not fitting to the entire height of the mobile view?**

Note I will be using this with an AngularJS project therefore I have two Divs which will wrap all of the contents, these are named as follows:

```
<div id="ui-view">
<div id"ResultsController">
```

**Why will the height in mobile view not set to 100% height?**

Comment: Try `height: 100vh!important;`.  `vmin` is relative to the smallest side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now `#main` height is the same as `width` value. On `#main` change to:

```
#main {
  background: red;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

It will fix your problem. `min-height` or just `height`. `vh` means viewport height, so it will cover all view.

Answer (score 1):

When working with mobile it is best to work with `vh` , which is viewport height, and `vw`, which is viewport width.

For your element you'd want to do the following:

`#main {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  min-height: 100vh; // vh = viewport height`